# Read stdClass Object in php

Tags: php, arrays, soap, stdclass

When I send data from ASP.net to PHP, I want to read data using SoapClient
like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [HelloWorldResult] => stdClass Object ( [string] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 4546330305913 [2] => 1395/11/20 [3] => 0 ) ) )
```

How do I access the 1st element of the array (i.e. `Array[0]`)?

Comment: `var_dump($HelloWorldResult->string[0]);` ?

Comment: Tnx .$res1=$res->HelloWorldResult->string[1];
echo $res1;

Comment: Great. I added it as an answer. Thank for validate it if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read your object.

It says that it's a standard object who contains a standard object who contains an array. So, first tell about first object than second object to end with the array's name followed by key you want to get :

```
$some_obj->HelloWorldResult->string[0]
```

For an example :

```
$some_obj = new stdClass();
$some_obj->HelloWorldResult = new stdClass();
$some_obj->HelloWorldResult->string = array(
    0,
    4546330305913,
    "1395/11/20",
    0
);

print_r($some_obj);
```

Output :

> ```
> stdClass Object
> (
>     [HelloWorldResult] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [string] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 0
>             [1] => 4546330305913
>             [2] => 1395/11/20
>             [3] => 0
>         )
>     )
> )
> ```

Then to access some value :

```
var_dump($some_obj->HelloWorldResult->string[0]);
```

Output :

> ```
> int(0)
> ```